# Find a relationship between constants a,b,c which makes the following system consistent.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Find a relationship between constants a,b,c which makes the following system consistent.
-3x + y - z = a
x       + z = b
- x + y + z = c

Here's my work:
-3 1 -1 | a , 
1  0  1 | b , 
-1 1  1 | c

1  0  1 | b , 
-3 1 -1 | a , 
-1 1  1 | c

1 0 1 | b , 
0 1 2 | 3b+a ,
0 1 2 | b+c

1 0 1 | b , 
0 1 2 | 3b+a , 
0 0 0 | 2b+a+c

I am stuck here. I have tried using:
2b+a+c = 0 , 
x + z = b , 
y + 2z = 3b+a

Comment: manipulate the parts and solve for the relationships ??

Comment: You are done $2b+a+c = 0$ *is* the relationship.  If that is not the case these equations just won't work.  But if that is the case the equations will.

Comment: I am very confused by your formatting.  Could you please [MathJax-ify](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) your work?  It would make it much easier for peons like me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I) $-3x + y - z = a$

II) $x + z = b$

III) $-x + y + z = c$.

But $c= -x + y+z = (-3x + y-z) + 2(-x +y+z) = a + 2b$.

These equations are not independent.

So $c = a + 2b$ *must* be true for this system of equations to be consistent.

And if $c = a + 2b$ this system reduces down to

$-3x+y - z =a$

$x + z =b$

So

$x = b - z$

$y = a  +3b -2z$

Which are two linear independent equations with 3 variables.  $a,b$ may be any value so long as $c = a + 2b$.